# Send request and receive response through XMLHttprequest and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I am new to node js. I am trying to send a POST request to node server (node.js)on a button click through XMLHttprequest. I need to get responseText from node server. And I don't want to use express for this. When I click on the button node js is doing nothing. Please correct me.

**node.js file** :

```
var http=require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
if(req.method=='POST'){
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
    res.write("hello");
    res.end();}
}).listen(2020);
```

**Javascript.js:**

```
function test_nodejs(){
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST",'http://localhost:2020',true);
xhttp.send(null);
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        alert(xhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

**Output:** 
[image: Clicked on 'Get' button but received no response text]

Comment: Use the Network tab of your browser's devtools to troubleshoot this. It will show your POST request and your server's response.

Comment: Checked Network tab in developer tools. I see no log recorded for POST and response activities. I think the issue is with ports and URL I think. HTML is running at port 8080 and Node.js is running at 2020. Not sure where is it going wrong.